# Partially applied type constructors in instance declarations

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a type constructor

```
type SimpleFcn α m = m α -> m α
```

and I want to use it in a class where it will be further parameterized later. Namely,

```
instance A (SimpleFcn α)
```

In my situation, any functions in the class `A` would be parametric in argument `m`.

```
class A β where f :: Monad m => β m
instance A (SimpleFcn α) where f x = x
```

What is an appropriate workaround for this situation?

Comment: It seems like you forgot to ask the actual question, or maybe I just don't see it.

Comment: Let's be clear that such a type declaration creates a type synonym, not a type constructor. Type constructors, as declared by data, newtype, data family, have kinds and exist as first class type level things. Type synonyms do not have kinds: they are not first class things. When applied to their given arity of things, they make things. Note that you can define type synonyms at any kind, e.g. type Foo = Map Int. You can use Foo in an instance (e.g. Functor Foo) because it is applied to the given type synonym parameters, even though Foo can indeed be applied to a type.

Comment: @pigworker: You should make that into an answer.

Comment: I would argue that type synonyms have kinds.  Just try to use one in the wrong way and you'll get a kind error.

Comment: @augustss What's an example of "the wrong way" of using type synonyms?

Comment: @is7s A wrong definition: `type T x = (x, x Int)`.  A wrong use `type T = Int; x :: T Bool`.  A type synonym has a kind, but it also has an arity (the number of arguments in the definition).  It always has to be used with at least as many arguments as in the definition.  For instance `type L1 x = [x]; type L2 = []` are similar, but `L1` always needs an argument, so `instance Monad L1` is wrong, whereas `instance Monad L2` is OK.

Comment: @pigworker: With GHC's liberal type synonyms extension it can become harder to justify that perspective--they're still not first class entities, and can't be used as in the question, but you can partially apply them enough to do things like write Church numeral arithmetic with type synonyms alone. If nothing else, it seems like they must have kinds in some reasonable sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to partitially apply type synonyms, as they are just a way to shorten your code and not real type-level lambdas. You can try to use a `newtype` instead.